# ScrollSpy active class not triggering in nav menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm building a custom nav menu in a wordpress site which uses Affix and ScrollSpy (both are Bootstrap plugins.)

I've been testing my code by pasting it into the chrome js console. Affix works fine but ScrollSpy doesn't trigger.

Here's the JS I'm pasting into the console:

```
jQuery('body').css('position', 'relative');

jQuery('.menu-scrollspy-affix-test-container').attr('id', 'scrollspy-target').addClass('scrollspy');
jQuery('#menu-scrollspy-affix-test').addClass('nav');
jQuery('body').scrollspy({target: '#scrollspy-target'});

    jQuery('.nav').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 100,
        bottom: function () {
          return (this.bottom = jQuery('#footer').outerHeight(true))
        }
      }
    })
```

The above code produces the following results:

- `style="position: relative;"` is added to the `<body>` tag
- `id="scrollspy-target"` and `class="scrollspy"` are added to the parent (`div.menu-scrollspy-affix-test-container`) of the ul menu (`ul#menu-scrollspy-affix-test`)
- `class="nav`" is added to the nav menu (`ul#menu-scrollspy-affix-test`)
- `data-spy="scroll"` is added to the `<body>`
- Affix code is applied to `.nav`. (Affix seems to work perfectly)

The 'active' class is supposed to be applied to each li in the nav menu when you scroll to the corresponding anchor in the page. For example:

```
<div class="menu-scrollspy-affix-test-container">
    <ul id="menu-scrollspy-affix-test" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-12421" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12421"><a href="#intro">Intro Section</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12422" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12422"><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12423" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12423"><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-12424" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12424"><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
<h1 id="intro">Intro Text</h1>
<p>...</p>
<h1 id="section1"></h1>
<p>...</p>

etc...
```

However, no "active" classes are being applied.

I've read over the bootstrap documentation about a hundred times, and have done a bunch of troubleshooting. Just not sure where to go from here - it seems like I've followed the instructions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you described above.. Did you found the problem yet?